# An error "Request method POST not supported" with form:checkbox

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, checkbox

I want to do a mcq with Spring mvc. I've got a class Mcq with a OneToMany relationship with the class Question, which has a OneToMany relationship with the class Answer. Thus Mcq have as property an Arraylist ListOfQuestions, and Question an Arraylist ListOfAnswers.

My controller is

```
    @RequestMapping(value="displayMcq", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showMcq(Model model) {
    Mcq mcq = mcqService.findById(new Long(1));
    model.addAttribute("mcq", mcq);
return "displayMcq";
}   

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String displayQcmRepondu(@ModelAttribute("mcq2") Mcq mcq, BindingResult binding, SessionStatus status) {      
     if (binding.hasErrors()) {
         return "displayMcq";

 } else {
     status.setComplete();
     return "redirect:/mcqSuccess/";
    }
}
```

and my view displayMcq.jsp is

```
<form:form modelAttribute="mcq" method="POST">
        <ol>
            <c:forEach items="${mcq.listOfQuestions}" var="question">
                <li>
                    <c:out value="${question.label}" /> 
                    <br />
                    <ul>
                        <c:forEach var="answer" items="${question.listOfAnswers}">
                            <form:checkbox path="listOfQuestions" value="answer.id" label="${answer.label}" />
                            <br />
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Validate" />
    </form:form>
```

My mcq is well displayed but the processing of the form fails. I stay on the displayMcq appearance with the error "Etat HTTP 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported".

So, could you explain me the problem, help me to proccess my mcq correctly and return the checked answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your controller methods are mapped to different URLs (due to absence of `value` attribute on your POST method).

Since you don't have `action` attribute in `<form:form>`, it sends a POST request to the current page's URL on submit, but you don't have controller methods to handle POST request to that URL.

So, you need to map your POST method to the same URL as your GET method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="displayMcq", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String displayQcmRepondu(...) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that solved one problem, but when I validated, I had a message error like "Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String[] to required type java.util.List for property...".

So I modified the controller method as

```
    @RequestMapping(value="displayQcm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String displayQcmRepondu(@ModelAttribute ("mcqProcess") Mcq mcq, BindingResult binding, Model model, SessionStatus status) {      
     model.addAttribute("mcqProcess", mcq);
     status.setComplete();
     return "mcqSuccess";
 }
```

where I want to display the checked answers in mcqSuccess.jsp but the mcq was not submitted. I show the page, but juste the written text.

If it can help, the mcqSuccess is

```
<h2>MCQ submitted</h2>
    <ol>
        <c:forEach items="${mcqProcess.listOfQuestions}" var="question">
            <li>
                <c:out value="${question.label}" />
                <br/>
                    <ul>
                        <c:forEach var = "answer" items = "${question.listOfAnswers}">
                            <c:if test = "${answer.correct}">                               
                            <c:out value = "${answer.label}" />
                            </c:if>
                            <br/>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>

    </ol>
</div>
```